# How to Add drop downs in a particular range of Excel cells using vb-script?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to add drop-down list to a particular range of cells(say D2 to D100).
There are 5 items in the drop-down list: Add, Remove, Validate, Modify,No Action.

I have tried to use the code which was available in Stack Overflow already but I have not been completely successful with it. The below code uses Range.Validate syntax.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWB1 =objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Kaushik\Desktop\Test.xlsx")
Set objWS1 = objWB1.Worksheets("Test")

objWS1.Cells(2,26).Value="Add"
objWS1.Cells(3,26).Value="Remove"
objWS1.Cells(4,26).Value="Validate"
objWS1.Cells(5,26).Value="Modify"
objWS1.Cells(6,26).Value="No Action"

With objWS1.Range("D2:D" & objWS1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Validation
    .Add 3,1,1, "=$Z$2:$Z$6"
    .IgnoreBlank=True
    .InCellDropdown=True
    .InputTitle=""
    .ErrorTitle=""
    .InputMessage=""
    .ErrorMessage=""
    .ShowInput=True
    .ShowError=True
end With
```

The above code which I have used needs me to add the List in particular cells of the excel and then use those cells to add to the drop down in the defined range. But I do not want to keep that list in my excel and as I delete them the drop down values also becomes blank.
Please help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried For Your Requirement. Please Find it below code

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

For i = 1 To 100

  With objWorkbook1.Sheets(1).Range("D" & i).Validation
    .Add 3, 1, 1, "Add,Remove,Validate,Modify,No Action"'''''Here Your Drop Down List'''''
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "Overwrite"
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
  end With
  Next

 objWorkbook2.SaveAs("C:\Users\ECE-Kishore27\Desktop\Output.xlsx")
 objWorkbook2.Close


objExcel.Quit
set objExcel=nothing
```